# How to add a real-time count-up timer in each row getting from my database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I need to show hours, minutes, and seconds which the orders is loaded to my monitor page where i got from mysql db and using foreach loop. i'm still new to javascript and i'm having problem on count-up timers which is executing same time from my first row result.

[Here is my sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4Q8B.png)

Here is my Ajax Code:

```
    /* AJAX request to checker */
    function check(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/kds1/monitor/checker',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                counter:$('#dispatch-list').data('counter')
            }
        }).done(function( response ) {
            /* update counter */
            $('#dispatch-list').data('counter',response.current);
            /* check if with response we got a new update */
            if(response.update==true){
                if(response.patch==false){
                    $('#title-un').text('New Order Added');
                    $('#para-un').text('There are new addition to the order, kindly check the food preparation or miscellaneous tab. thanks!');
                    $('#update-notification').fadeIn(1500);
                    $('#update-notification').delay(3000).fadeOut(1500);
                    $('#order-list').html(response.orders);
                    $('#misc-list').html(response.misc);
                    $('#dispatch-list').html(response.dispatch);
                    $('#reject-list').html(response.reject);
                } else {
                    $('#order-list').html(response.orders);
                    $('#misc-list').html(response.misc);
                    $('#dispatch-list').html(response.dispatch);
                    $('#reject-list').html(response.reject);
                }
                //$('#counter-list').html(response.counters);
            }
        });
    }
    //Every 5 sec check if there is new update
    setInterval(check,5000);
    //end of checker
```

And here is my controller

```
public function checker()
{
    //set initial value of update to false
    $data['update'] = false;

    //get current counter
    $cc = $this->order_model->check_changes();
    foreach($cc as $row){
        $data['current'] = $row->counter;
    }

    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['counter']) && $_POST['counter']!=$data['current']){
        $data['orders']   = $this->order_model->get_order_buttons(1);
        $data['misc']     = $this->order_model->get_order_buttons(2);
        $data['dispatch'] = $this->order_model->get_order_buttons(3);
        $data['reject']   = $this->order_model->get_order_buttons(4);
        $data['update'] = true;
        $data['patch'] = true;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

And here is my model, here are all the buttons where i am showing the count-up timer

```
public function get_order_buttons($id)
{
    $this->mysql->select('id, trans_no, room_no, date, HOUR(time_in) as hour, MINUTE(time_in) as minute, time_in, SUM(qty) as qty1, GROUP_CONCAT(description) as description, post, code, status, type');
    $this->mysql->from('orders');
       $date = date('Y-m-d');
       $dateMin = date('Y-m-d',(strtotime ( '-1 day' , strtotime ( $date) ) ));
       $where = "((`date` = '".$dateMin."' AND `time_in` >= '22:00:00') OR (`date` = '".$date."' AND `time_in` >= '00:00:00'))";
    $this->mysql->where($where);
    if($id == 1){
        //orders
        $this->mysql->where('status', 0);
        $this->mysql->where('type', 1);
    } elseif($id == 2){
        //misc
        $this->mysql->where('status', 0);
        $this->mysql->where('type', 0);
    } elseif($id == 3){
        //dispatch
        $this->mysql->where('status', 1);
    } elseif($id == 4){
        //rejected items
        $this->mysql->where('status', 3);
    }
    $this->mysql->group_by('trans_no');
    $this->mysql->order_by('date, hour, minute', 'ASC');

    $query = $this->mysql->get();
    $results = $query->result();

        $clr = '';
        $result = '';
        foreach($results as $row){
            if($row->status == 0 && $row->type == 1){
                $btn = 'onclick="show_order('.$row->trans_no.')"';
                $clr = 'btn-success';
            }elseif($row->status == 0 && $row->type == 0){
                $btn = 'onclick="show_misc('.$row->trans_no.')"';
                $clr = 'btn-success';
            }elseif($row->status == 1){
                $btn = 'onclick="show_dispatch('.$row->trans_no.')"';
            }elseif($row->status == 3){
                $btn = 'onclick="show_reject('.$row->trans_no.')"';
                $clr = 'bg-navy';
            }
            $result .= '<a '.$btn.' class="btn '.$clr.' btn-success btn-social" style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;margin-right:10px;">
                        <i class="fa">'.$row->room_no.'</i> 00:00:00 
                    </a>';
        }
    return $result;
}
```

And i have this working sample that i got from here but i don't know where i should put it, if i include the span on my foreach loop, it's just getting the first row.

```
    <span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var upgradeTime = 172801;
var seconds = upgradeTime;
function timer() {
    var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
    var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
    var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
    var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
    var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Completed";
    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
}
var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
</script>
```

[its already working here, but i really need a javascript the will make it real-time counting-upward](https://i.stack.imgur.com/549wn.png)

Comment: Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There are many questions here about creating a counter.

Comment: You can add to your select statement: SELECT TIMEDIFF(TIME(NOW()),time_in) AS timeElapsed then in your results change <i class="fa">'.$row->room_no.'</i> 00:00:00 to <i class="fa">'.$row->room_no.'</i> '.$row->timeElapsed NOTE: sometimes the database server has a different time setting to that of the web server. If this is the case then you will need to look at other options/settings.

Comment: Hi RobG, i already edited it, is it right? thanks!

Comment: hi jeff, i also have a column on my database which includes the time when it is punched to the system. i just dont know how i can load it using the javascript. thanks!

Comment: and also i really need it real-time count-up using javascript its like you have timer on the orders.

Comment: hey jeff it works!, but i really need it real-time counting. what should i do?